# ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 3 but has shape (480, 640, 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have this code which reduces a color to a minimal amount of colors to help identify what it is; it was working earlier, but now it says

```
ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 3 but has shape (480, 640, 4)
```

Like I said it was working earlier, but then I tried adding 'white' because white turns to yellow and now it doesn't work at all

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import colors
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree as KDTree
from scipy.misc import face
from PIL import Image

REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE = True

# borrow a list of named colors from matplotlib
if REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE:
    use_colors = {k: colors.cnames[k] for k in ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'black', 'yellow', 'purple']}
else:
    use_colors = colors.cnames

# translate hexstring to RGB tuple
named_colors = {k: tuple(map(int, (v[1:3], v[3:5], v[5:7]), 3*(16,)))
                for k, v in use_colors.items()}
ncol = len(named_colors)


if REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE:
    ncol -= 1
    no_match = named_colors.pop('purple')
else:
    no_match = named_colors['purple']

# make an array containing the RGB values 
color_tuples = list(named_colors.values())
color_tuples.append(no_match)
color_tuples = np.array(color_tuples)

color_names = list(named_colors)
color_names.append('no match')

# get example picture
img = Image.open('apple.png')

# build tree
tree = KDTree(color_tuples[:-1])
# tolerance for color match `inf` means use best match no matter how
# bad it may be
tolerance = np.inf
# find closest color in tree for each pixel in picture
dist, idx = tree.query(img, distance_upper_bound=tolerance)
# count and reattach names
counts = dict(zip(color_names, np.bincount(idx.ravel(), None, ncol+1)))

print(counts)

import pylab

pylab.imshow(img)
pylab.savefig('apple.png')
pylab.clf()
pylab.imshow(color_tuples[idx])
pylab.savefig('minimal.png' if REDUCED_COLOR_SPACE else 'reduced.png')
```

It did work before:

[image: Before]

And it did work after:

[image: After]

**The problem is:**
When I run it, I get this error

> 'line 45, in  dist, idx = tree.query(img, distance_upper_bound=tolerance)
>   File "ckdtree.pyx", line 754, in scipy.spatial.ckdtree.cKDTree.query
>   ValueError: x must consist of vectors of length 3 but has shape (480, 640, 4)'

I expect it to take a picture I choose and change it like in the example I posted above.

How can I realize this?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what problem are you experimenting and what is the result you expect?

Comment: @Neb any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is self-explanatory. It means that your Image is in `RGBA` mode, i.e. it has alpha channel in it, so its shape is `(640, 480, 4)` and the channels are R, G, B, **A**.

That being said, you need to first convert your image to `RGB`:

```
img = img.convert("RGB")
```

Then, I experimented [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10342#issuecomment-365209852) issue and the only way I found to solve it is to convert your colors into `uint8` format:

Change this line:

```
color_tuples = np.array(color_tuples)
```

with:

```
color_tuples = np.array(color_tuples).astype('uint8')
```

Hope it helps!